# Domain of a double integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have to express this domain in a normal way:

$ D:= \{ 1 \leq xy \leq 2; \ x \leq y \leq e^x \}$

I thought of write the first condition as $ \frac{1}{x} \leq y \leq \frac{2}{x} $ Because in the conditions $x$ can't be $0$ so there is no loss of solutions.

Now i'm lost because of the fact that $ \frac{2}{x} = e^x $ has no algebraic solutions. I have also tried with polar coordinates, but they (clearly) don't work.

Comment: What are you considering the "normal" way to express a domain?

Comment: I consider a form of the domain like $ \{ x \in [a,b] ; f(x) \leq y \leq g(x)\} $